# Dictionary database and real time searching

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm writing an English dictionary for Windows Phone for my own purposes, and I would like to know if it is worth to store words in database, or maybe I should store them in regular txt file. I want to search for matching words in real time ( while user is typing word), and I am worrying, that database won't yield me a proper efficiency. Are my concerns justifable?

Comment: How many words do you plan to have in your database/file?

Comment: Adding @Marco if number of words are less, you better off read them into main memory and search from there.Be it text file or database.

Comment: I would consider embeded databases that support full text search on Windows Phone platforms.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want a DAWG: [Directed Acyclic Word Graph](http://www.wutka.com/dawg.html)

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be fine like some apps from android like meriam webster, the only thing you should consider is the size of your file because it can affect the performance of your phone by doing that kind of thing.

Comment: All data in txt file occupy about 7 mB , thanks for your answers, I'll try database at first, and if it will happen to be to slow, I'll switch to text file loaded into memory.

Comment: @MaksymilianGasztych make sure youre queries are optimized for smallest effect on the performance of the phone.

also mark an answer as answered if it is correct thanks